# Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variadic-functions, spread-syntax, rest-parameters

I am confused about the spread syntax and rest parameter in ES2015. Can anybody explain the difference between them with proper examples?

Comment: One is at the call site, the other is in the parameter list. Or for arrays, one is in the literal, the other is in a destructuring expression.

Comment: Can anybody explain why it is downvoted?

Comment: Probably because of no shown research effort. Also, where did you find those terms, where/how were they so bad explained that you cannot tell the difference?

Comment: Thanks @Bergi  but I was in hurry.

Comment: @Bergi personal opinion, your comments offer more insights than the accepted answer,  simply stating `expanding` vs `collapsing` doesn't tell their use case, thanks ;)

Comment: You can refer this blog for rest / spread operator - https://tejassavaliya.medium.com/es6-use-of-spread-rest-operator-in-javascript-f13b061b522f

Comment: I would probably ***not*** close this question as a duplicate of
[What do these three dots in React do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31048953).
Why?
Because this question explicitly deals with **both** the *rest* parameters syntax and the *spread* syntax, whereas the other question *mainly* deals with the spread syntax.
More important than closing one of these two questions, they are now linked to one another.
This makes them both easier to find.

Comment: See an article https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread

Comment: @Henke Moreoever, that question deals with spread syntax in JSX tags, not in object literals.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

When using spread, you are expanding a single variable into more:

```js
var abc = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var def = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var alpha = [ ...abc, ...def ];
console.log(alpha)// alpha == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
```

When using rest arguments, you are collapsing all remaining arguments of a function into one array:

```js
function sum( first, ...others ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < others.length; i++ )
        first += others[i];
    return first;
}
console.log(sum(1,2,3,4))// sum(1, 2, 3, 4) == 10;
```

Comment: what about `const [a, b, ...c] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Comment: @yukulélé this is `rest`. Read it as `a`, `b` and the rest of the array.

Comment: @Yukulélé its rest and the value of c will be [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: You can refer this blog for rest / spread operator - https://tejassavaliya.medium.com/es6-use-of-spread-rest-operator-in-javascript-f13b061b522f

Answer (score 97):

ES6 has new feature three dots `...`

Here is how we can use these dots:

> 1. As Rest/Collector/Gather

```js
var [c, ...m] = [1,2,3,4,5]; // m -> [2,3,4,5]
```

Here `...m` is a collector, it collects the rest of the parameters. Internally when we write:

`var [c, ...m] = [1,2,3,4,5];`
JavaScript does following

```js
var c = 1,
    m = [2, 3, 4, 5];
```

> 2. As Spread

```js
var params = [ "hello", true, 7 ];
var other = [ 1, 2, ...params ]; // other => [1,2,"hello", true, 7]
```

Here, `...params` spreads so as to adding all of its elements to `other`

Internally JavaScript does following

```js
var other = [1, 2].concat(params);
```

Answer (score 18):

### Summary:

In javascript the `...` is overloaded. It performs a different operations based on where the operator is used:

1. When used in function arguments of a function **declaration/expression** it will convert the remaining arguments into an array. This variant is called the **Rest parameters** syntax.
2. In other cases it will spread out the values of an iterable in places where zero or more arguments (function calls) or elements (array literals) are expected. This variant is called the **Spread** syntax.

### Example:

**Rest parameter syntax:**

```js
function rest(first, second, ...remainder) {
  console.log(remainder);
}

// 3, 4 ,5 are the remaining parameters and will be 
// merged together in to an array called remainder 
rest(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

**Spread syntax:**

```js
// example from MDN:

function sum(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3];

// the numbers array will be spread over the 
// x y z parameters in the sum function
console.log(sum(...numbers));


// the numbers array is spread out in the array literal
// before the elements 4 and 5 are added
const newNumbers = [...numbers, 4, 5];

console.log(newNumbers);
```

Comment: The first part of the spread syntax example appears to be taken from
[JavaScript Demo: Expressions - Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#content).
Nothing wrong with that as long as you attribute.
This is what we want others to do when getting content from us. See
[Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/a)
and
[Defending Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/11/d).

Answer (score 7):

Javascript's **three dots ( `...` ) operator** can be used in two different ways:

1. **Rest parameter**: collects all remaining elements into an array.

```js
var days = ["Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"];
const [sat, sun, ...weekdays] = days;
console.log(sat); // "Sat"
console.log(sun); // "Sun"
console.log(weekdays); // ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
```

2. **Spread operator**: allows iterables( arrays / objects / strings ) to be expanded into single arguments/elements.

```js
var weekdays = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"];
var days = [...weekdays, "Sat", "Sun"]; 
console.log(days) // ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
```

Note that the spread operator can be the first element, but *the rest parameter needs to be the last* to collect the rest elements .

Comment: *[T]he rest parameter needs to be the last to collect the rest elements*.
~ * ~ Confirmed.
Good point! Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

> When we see "..." in the code, it is either rest parameters or the
>   spread operator.
>
> There’s an easy way to distinguish between them:
>
> When ... is at the end of function parameters, it’s “rest parameters”
>   and gathers the rest of the list into the array. When ... occurs in a
>   function call or alike, it’s called a “spread operator” and expands an
>   array into the list. Use patterns:
>
> Rest parameters are used to create functions that accept any number of
>   arguments. The spread operator is used to pass an array to functions
>   that normally require a list of many arguments. Together they help to
>   travel between a list and an array of parameters with ease.
>   For more information about this [click here](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread-operator)

Answer (score 3):

Added in ES6 these three dots `...` has two meanings, Spread operator and Rest parameter

Spread operator: You use the three dots to expand `iterables`, by `iterables` I mean `arrays`, `string`, etc. As arguments. For example `Math.max()` function expect an indeterminate number of arguments so you can use Spread operator to expand elements as arguments on `Math.max()` function. Here an example from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```
console.log(Math.max(1, 3, 2));
// expected output: 3

console.log(Math.max(-1, -3, -2));
// expected output: -1

var array1 = [1, 3, 2];

console.log(Math.max(...array1));
// expected output: 3
```

Another use case is to add, for example having this array

```
const videoGames = ['mario galaxy', 'zelda wind waker', 'ico'];
```

You can add it to another array

```
const favoritesVideoGames = ['Shadow of the colosus', ...videoGames];
```

Then `favoritesVideoGames` value is

```
[ 'Shadow of the colosus', 'mario galaxy', 'zelda wind waker', 'ico' ]
```

About Rest parameter, here the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) definition

> The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number
>   of arguments as an array.

This means you can pack many elements into a single element

Here an example from MDN

```
function sum(...theArgs) {
  return theArgs.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous + current;
  });
}

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
// expected output: 6

console.log(sum(1, 2, 3, 4));
// expected output: 10
```

I usually get confused with these three points, this [illustration](https://twitter.com/stephaniecodes/status/1029453269242990594) by [@stephaniecodes](https://twitter.com/stephaniecodes) helps me to remember its logic. I mention that I took inspiration from this illustration to answer this question.

I hope it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Simple to remember ............

if the triple dots (...) are on the left side its Rest paramenter, if the triple dots are on the right side its Spread parameter.

Remember **LRS** alphabetically its L then R then S

```
const [a,b,...c] = [1,2,3,4,5]     // (left) rest

const [d,e] = [1, ...c]             // (right) spread
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically like in Python:

```py
>>> def func(first, *others):
...    return [first, *others]
>>> func('a', 'b', 'c')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Python examples to a JavaScript question with no explanation of the difference between `rest` and `spread` doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to this [i cant understand how we are passing a function and returning arguments in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076765/i-cant-understand-how-we-are-passing-a-function-and-returning-arguments-in-javas)

Function is a set of instructions that takes some input and processes them and returns result.

here we have an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], and filter function iterates over each element and passes each element to positive functions which returns the number if it is even, else skips it.

trace:

```
1 => Filter(1) => positive(1) => skips 1,
2 => Filter(2) => positive(2) => returns 2,
3 => Filter(3) => positive(3) => skips 3,
...
6 => Filter(6) => positive(6) => returns 6
```

hence the result
[2, 4, 6]

Answer (score 0):

considering 3 scenarios

1] without using any operator

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // returns 3  (function will takes first 2 arg only)
```

2] with rest operator

```
function add(...args) {
  let result = 0;

  for (let arg of args) result += arg;

  return result
}

add(1) // returns 1
add(1,2) // returns 3
add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // returns 15
```

*- we can gather any number of arguments into an array*

3] with spread operator

```
const arr = ["Joy", "Wangari", "Warugu"];
const newArr = ["joykare", ...arr];

The value of newArr will be [ 'joykare', 'Joy', 'Wangari', 'Warugu' ]
```

another one

```
function add(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c ;
}
const args = [1, 2, 3];

add(...args);

-We have been using arrays to demonstrate the spread operator, 
but any iterable also works. So, if we had a 
string const str = 'joykare', [...str] translates to [ 'j', 'o', 'y', 'k', 'a', 'r', 'e' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

From: Ved Antani, Stoyan Stefanov Book “Object-Oriented JavaScript - Third Edition.” :

**Rest parameters**

**ES6** introduces **rest** parameters. **Rest** parameters allow us to send an arbitrary number of parameters to a function in the form of an array. **Rest** parameter can only be the last one in the list of parameters, and there can only be one rest parameter. Putting a **rest operator(...)** before the last formal parameter indicates that parameter is a rest parameter. The following example shows adding a rest operator before the last formal parameter:

```
function sayThings(tone, ...quotes){ 
  console.log(Array.isArray(quotes)); //true 
  console.log(`In ${tone} voice, I say ${quotes}`) 
} 
sayThings("Morgan Freeman","Something serious"," 
 Imploding Universe"," Amen"); 
//In Morgan Freeman voice, I say Something serious,
 Imploding Universe,Amen
```

The first parameter passed to the function is received in tone, while the rest of the parameters are received as an array. Variable arguments (var-args) have been part of several other languages and a welcome edition to **ES6**. **Rest** parameters can replace the slightly controversial arguments variable. The major difference between rest parameters and the arguments variable is that the rest parameters are real arrays. All array methods are available to **rest** parameters.

**Spread operators**

A **spread** operator looks exactly like a **rest** operator but performs the exact opposite function. **Spread** operators are used while providing arguments while calling a function or defining an array. The **spread** operator **takes an array** and **splits its element** into individual variables. The following example illustrates how the **spread** operator provides a much clearer syntax while calling functions that take an array as an argument:

```
function sumAll(a,b,c){ 
  return a+b+c 
} 
var numbers = [6,7,8] 
//ES5 way of passing array as an argument of a function 
console.log(sumAll.apply(null,numbers)); //21 
//ES6 Spread operator 
console.log(sumAll(...numbers))//21
```