# How does the spread syntax in ES6 JS work as a function argument?

Tags: javascript, operators, spread-syntax

OK, so I'm trying to understand how the new spread works as a function parameter. Imagine a function with an unknown number of parameters and adds them all together.

```
let addNums = ...a => a.reduce ((a,b) => a+b);
```

This function obviously works. So, what's my problem? Well here's some observations, followed by my problem:

1. **the spread syntax as a function parameter / argument seems designed to 'spread' an array of values as separate arguments:**

Based on the research I've done, the spread syntax can be used to pass arrays to functions that will not accept arrays as arguments as standard, e.g. Array.prototype.push(), without having to use `apply`:

```
var x = [];
var y = [1,2,3];
// where Array.push(arg1,arg2,...) requires separate arguments this is now possible:
x.push(...y);
// which 'spreads' 'y' into separate arguments: x.push (arg1,arg2,...)
```

but the Array passed to `push` in this case needs to be declared/defined beforehand (in this case `y`)

2. **this is confirmed by looking at the length of the arguments object inside the function**

if I use `addNums(1,2,3,4)`, `arguments.length` is still == 4. So, it seems that the function is also still being called as `addNums(1,2,3,4)`

**THE PROBLEM**

My problem is that I'm not calling `addNums` with an array as an argument for the spread syntax to process. I'm NOT calling `addNums([1,2,3,...])` The behaviour I'm struggling to understand is that there seems to be a secret hidden step where, given a function declared with the spread syntax as its single argument:

```
let x =  ...someSetOfValues => return something ;
```

and then called with a list of arguments:

```
x(1,2,3,4,...);
```

there's the generation of the `arguments` object **AND** a variable of type `Array` is *also* created with the *same name as the function parameter with the spread syntax*.

Perhaps this is obvious or trivial to more experienced coders, but this seems to me to be counter-intuitive to the use cases put forward so far like *spreading an array of values across a set of parameters of unknown length*.

In fact, I would go so far to say as rather than *reading and splitting* an array across parameters, when a function is called with multiple parameters, but defined with a single parameter with the spread syntax, the spread syntax actually acts as something similar to : `Array.apply(null, arguments)` or `var a = [arg1, arg2, ...]` - ** it is a creator not a spreader **

Sources for my research:

- http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_Syntax
- [Spread Syntax ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6)

particularly the comment on the question "@void Mostly for use in function calls, I.e. if myFunc takes an unknown number of arguments, we can give it arguments as an array with spread. Like this: myFunc(...dynamicallyGeneratedArgs)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I was able to find a reference to what are called *rest* parameters.

Rest parameters look like they use the `...` spread syntax  as part of the parameter, but behave differently. They will in fact collect an indefinite number of arguments/parameters and then make them available as an array inside the function.

Source: [link to MDN description of 'rest' parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

Basically the behaviour that I observed in the first place!