# How does `new Array(5).map()` work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've recently discovered that mapping an uninitialised array doesn't seem to work as I would expect. With this code:

```js
function helloMap(value, index) {
    return "Hello " + index;
}

console.clear();

var initialArray = Array.apply(null, new Array(5));

console.log("Array initialised with apply:");
console.log(initialArray);
console.log(initialArray.map(helloMap));

var normalArray = new Array(5);

console.log("Array constructed normally");
console.log(normalArray);
console.log(normalArray.map(helloMap));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I get different results despite the first output for each array being `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

The fact that I get different results implies that the `undefined` in these 2 arrays are in fact different. In the first I suspect that the array has 5 items in, each one is undefined. In the second the array is 5 items long but there is nothing, not even undefined in there...

It's a bit confusing.

Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: small note...console.log(initialArray.map(helloMap); should be console.log(initialArray.map(helloMap)); missing paren and my edit queue is full so i can't just edit

Comment: related to: "Why does Array.apply(null, [args]) act inconsistently when dealing with sparse arrays?" [Link here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949976/why-does-array-applynull-args-act-inconsistently-when-dealing-with-sparse-a)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array - "this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values"

Comment: @JohnVandivier Never edit code blocks, you could fix a typo that was causing the problem.

Comment: @Feathercrown trust me I had verified it was not causing the issue before saying so

Comment: @JohnVandivier Ah, never mind then. That's fine. :)

Comment: [Read the first paragraph of the "Description" section.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752434/how-to-tell-between-undefined-array-elements-and-empty-slots

Comment: instead of `Array.apply(null, Array(length)).map(fn)` or the not working `Array(length).map(fn)` you can use `Array.from({length}, fn)`. Or you wrap that into a function `const array = (length=0, value=undefined) => typeof value === "function"? Array.from({length}, value): Array(+length).fill(value);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.apply(null, Array(5))` actually fills the array (or array-like object) that you pass as the second argument with the value of the first argument you pass in, as can be seen in the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

`new Array(5)` is just initializing an array with it's length property set to the argument of `5`. Again, as can be seen in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> If the only argument passed to the `Array` constructor is an integer between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its `length` property set to that number (**Note:** this implies an array of `arrayLength` empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values).

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's a bit easier to understand. Many thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 3):

According to MDN [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an
>   array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback
>   is invoked `only for indexes of the array which have assigned values`,
>   including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of the
>   array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been
>   deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

Both the arrays are different in the way Array.map executes the callback.
Since the array in second scenario doesn't have indexes `map` is returning empty

#### REASON

The answer lies in Array constructor

In the first scenario you are passing an array with length 5 to Array constructor which will `index the array based on the length` but in the second scenario you are just using the array with length 5

You will get to know the difference when you run `Object.keys(initialArray)` with `Object.keys(normalArray)`

Try checking the below example.

```js
function helloMap(value, index) {
    return "Hello " + index;
}

console.clear();

var initialArray = Array.apply(null, new Array(5));

console.log("Array initialised with apply:");
console.log(initialArray);
console.log(initialArray.map(helloMap));

var normalArray = new Array(5);

console.log("Array constructed normally");
console.log(normalArray);
console.log(normalArray.map(helloMap));

//DIFFERENCE
console.log("Initial Array: "+Object.keys(initialArray));
console.log("Normal Array: "+Object.keys(normalArray));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is not called on any elements of normalArray because there are no elements. Normal array is an array with 5 empty slots.

initialArray has 5 slots filled with `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I think here is your answer, [mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

`console.log(normalArray.map(helloMap));` will always fail, because it runs in the context - creates new array but won't work with undefined values.

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values, including undefined. **It is not called for missing elements of the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been deleted or which have never been assigned a value).**

Comment: I am sure you meant "mozilla" I updated my answer :)