# What's ES6 magic is happening in this React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm following this tutorial https://serverless-stack.com/ and am on https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/create-a-route-that-redirects.html

This introduces an `AuthenticatedRoute` which checks the value of a prop called `isAuthenticated` to decide weather or not to render the component or redirect the user to `login`

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default ({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest }) =>
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      cProps.isAuthenticated
        ? <C {...props} {...cProps} />
        : <Redirect
            to={`/login?redirect=${props.location.pathname}${props.location
              .search}`}
          />}
  />;
```

I get what it achieves, but I'm unsure as to how it's doing it.

Can someone explain to me what's going on with the following bits please?

- `component: C`
- `...rest`
- `<C {...props} {...cProps} />`

Comment: Here's a good place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spread Operator ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-operator-es6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AuthenticatedRoute` is a [Functional](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) (stateless) component - a function.

1. The component is invoked with the props as the 1st argument, and this line 
   `({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest })` [destructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props, and assign some of them to variables. The `component: C` extract the `component` property from the props object, and assigns it to variable `C`.
2. The `...rest` in `({ component: C, props: cProps, ...rest })` is part of the [ECMAScript's Object Rest/Spread Properties proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), and you need babel's [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) for it to work in current browsers. It creates a new object from all the object properties that weren't assigned to variables (the rest).
3. The `<C {...props} {...cProps} />` is react's [JSX spread attributes](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html), and it converts all the object (`props` and `cProps`) properties to component attributes (like writing key=value). Props in `cProps` will override the properties of `props` because they appear after them.

Answer (score 3):

component: C - In ES6 you can have default initialisation in case the parameter is not passed. Here component will be defaulted to C.

...rest- With ES6 you can spread the element of a data structure. Here rest may have the route path for the render function.

- Each element of cprops and props is passed as attribute to C component. Props in cProps will override the properties of props as they appear after them.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `Authenticated Route` is that is called High Order Component. `Authenticated Route` wrap your `Route` component and conditionally return `component: C` if user is authenticated or `Redirect` component.

- `component` its a simple props of `Authenticated Route` but its renamed to `C` in cause that react component must be capitalized.
- `props: cProps` its a props you want to receive to the component
- `props` its a `Route` render props that needs to be applied to the component, which the render method should return
- `...rest` its an object which contain any other props, basically refer to the `Route`
- About { ...someData } you have been answered above in comments

Then you can simply wrap use `<AuthenticatedRoute />` and pass props you need according to the information written above