# What do the three dots "..." do in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax

I have gone through the following JavaScript code:

```
 let num = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5];
 console.log([... new Set(nums)]); //which prints [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I did not understand what this `...` device (three dots) does in this example.

Comment: It's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Property with three dots (...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464211/javascript-property-with-three-dots)

Comment: still have no idea what does spread operator work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read [Iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) first;

```js
let nums = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5];
let setFromArray = new Set(nums);
let arrayFromSet_spread = [...setFromArray];
console.log("spread", arrayFromSet_spread);
 
// here the spread will iterate over iteratable and return current value

//arrayFromSet can be written without spread like this
let arrayFromSet_forOf = [];
for ( let el of setFromArray ) {
  arrayFromSet_forOf.push(el)
}
console.log("forOf",arrayFromSet_forOf);


// and the most naive way to iterate :)
let arrayFromSet_ManualIteration = [];
let setFromArrayIterator = setFromArray[Symbol.iterator]();
const firstElement = setFromArrayIterator.next();
const secondElement = setFromArrayIterator.next();
const thirdElement = setFromArrayIterator.next();
const fourthElement = setFromArrayIterator.next();
const fifthElement = setFromArrayIterator.next();
const sixthElement = setFromArrayIterator.next();

arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(firstElement);
arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(secondElement);
arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(thirdElement);
arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(fourthElement);
arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(fifthElement);
arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(sixthElement);

//you could just push values not the itaration object itself
//arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(firstElement.value);
//arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(secondElement.value);
//arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(thirdElement.value);
//arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(fourthElement.value);
//arrayFromSet_ManualIteration.push(fifthElement.value);

console.log('ManualIteration full objects',arrayFromSet_ManualIteration);
```

Comment: wonderful, that's a great job