# A piece of JS code is needed to use multiple times with different values and function names. How to do it efficiently?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that is like this:

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
<script>
var foo;
bar()
function bar() {
    var config = {
        a: "foo",
        b: "string",
        otherConfig1: ...
        otherConfig2: ...
        ...
    }
    
    foo = new NeoVis.default(config)
    foo.render();
    console.log(foo);
}
</script>
```

I want to have 8 more pieces of this, with different `foo`, `bar` and `string`. The `otherConfig`s are unchanged. I can simply duplicate them, but since the `otherConfig`s are very long, I would like to do this smarter. I have read about [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor), but since the function doesn't have any argument, I don't know how to apply this. I also try to move the `config` object outside of the function, but it seems that the code wouldn't run.

<sub>[Neovis](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js) is a library. I also ask this on Neovis's Github: [How to have multiple divs with different initial Cypher query?](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues/233)</sub>

Comment: maybe you could have a `otherConfigs` variable and then apply that using the `...` operator in all the declarations you require.

Comment: what is the `...` operator? Surely it's not the ellipsis that I use to simply say there is more values in the object, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464211/javascript-property-with-three-dots

Comment: Moving `config` outside the function shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a function to which you pass the `id`, `func`, `string` as parameters to generate a `function` into the `context` you prefer (probably `window`). I have implemented a dummy `NeoVis` for the sake of the test, you will need to use yours instead.

```js
var NeoVis = {
    default: function(config) {
        this.render = function() {};
    }
};

function myfunction(context, id, func, str) {
    context[id] = undefined;
    return context[func] = function() {
        var config = {
            a: id,
            b: str,
            //otherConfigs...
        };
        
        context[id] = new NeoVis.default(config);
        context[id].render();
        console.log(`function ${func} was called and ${id} is the id`);
    };
}

for (let item of document.querySelectorAll("#foo, #lorem, #dolor")) {
    myfunction(window, item.id, item.getAttribute("data-function"), item.innerText)();
}
```

```html
<div id="foo" data-function="bar">string1</div>
<div id="lorem" data-function="ipsum">string2</div>
<div id="dolor" data-function="es">string3</div>
```

[image]

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. It just prints the strings, and there is nothing in the log. Can you tell more about how to implement the proper `Neovis`? If your dummy one is based on `foo = new NeoVis.default(config); foo.render();`, then I think it should work?

Comment: @Ooker I have edited my answer by adding a picture that shows that stuff is logged. I have no information whatsoever about the `NeoVis` you are using. It's probably a library, but since no information was provided about it, I have implemented a dummy version of it so we can test the templating I have implemented. Please run the snippet above and take a look at the logs. You should have something similar to the image I have shared in my answer.

Comment: Ah I see. So if the library has already handled `NeoVis`, then I don't need to declare it again. I try to remove that dummy on your code, and.. it's only work in JSFiddle, but not in my local machine.  I open a new question to solve this, hope to see you there: [Why does the same code run at some places and not in others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70558494/3416774)

Comment: @Ooker exactly. The dummy implementation of resources is the exact technique of unit tests. We do not actually care about the correctness of `NeoVis` when we are to test the logic that generates the resources that are using it, for the problem-space of this issue we are agnostic about `NeoVis`, while, in the actual site we do care about making sure it works properly.