# Typescript/JavaScript - How to pass rest parameters to subsequent function as parameters and not as array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript/JavaScript question.

I created my own `log()` method where I could switch logging on demand (not important), but right now I use a simple `console.log()`. Here is the code:

```
log(message: any): void {
    console.log(message)
}
```

Recently I decided to pass multiple parameters, since `console.log` supports *any number of parameters* using like: `console.log(a, b, c)`. 
So, I decided to use [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and adjust my method to the following:

```
log(...message: any[]): void {
    console.log(message)
}
```

Works great. However, when I use my `log` method with any number parameters, the `console.log` outputs an array and not separate values as if I called it directly.
I can understand why, because the message could be seen as a single parameter of array type.
But how would I pass array to `console.log` (or any other alike function) and tell that it is not a single parameter of array type, but multiple parameters?

I would really like to avoid defining 10 optional parameters passing them as is :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spread Syntax ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6)

Comment: Also touches on spread syntax: [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898512/spread-syntax-vs-rest-parameter-in-es2015-es6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 2 options for doing this:

Option 1:

```
log(...message: any[]): void {
    console.log(...message)
}
```

Option 2: Use `Function.prototype.apply`.

E.g.

```
log(...message: any[]): void {
    console.log.apply(null, message)
}
```

This will apply your array of arguments as you expect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Thank you very much!, the first solution worked as expected, and there was no need to try second one :)