# How does the spread/rest operator in JS work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to fully understand how the spread/rest operator works in JS. I have read the MDN docs but it's still not fully clear to me.

I've included an example below where I've used it and it has worked as desired.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Samir',
    age: 27,
    favoriteBooks:[
      {title: 'The Iliad'},
      {title: 'The Brothers Karamazov'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Angela',
    age: 33,
    favoriteBooks:[
      {title: 'Tenth of December'},
      {title: 'Cloud Atlas'},
      {title: 'One Hundred Years of Solitude'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Beatrice',
    age: 42,
    favoriteBooks:[
      {title: 'Candide'}
    ]
  }
];

const books = users
  .map(user => user.favoriteBooks.map(book => book.title))
  .reduce((arr, titles) => [...arr, ...titles], []);
```

Comment: `[...arr, ...titles]` is equivalent to `[arr[0],arr[1],/*etc*/,titles[0],titles[1],/*etc*/]`, `...` just spreads the individual elements out into the structure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6/57680090

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many resources on this topic other than MDN if you search around.

> How does the spread and rest operators in JS work?

[JavaScript ES6: Spread Operator and Rest Parameters](https://medium.com/@luke_smaki/javascript-es6-spread-operator-and-rest-parameters-b3e89d112281)

[Javascript's three dots ( ... ): Spread vs rest operators](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/javascripts-three-dots-spread-vs-rest-operators543)

[Rest parameters and spread syntax](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread)

---

**Spread**

> The spread operator “spreads” the values in an iterable (arrays, strings)

Essentially, spread will iterate over each item of an array in this case. Outputting `array[0]` `array[1]` `array[2]` etc.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];

console.log([...a, ...b]); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

or

```
var a = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
test(...a);

function test(param1, param2, param3) {
    // param1 = 'x'
    // param2 = 'y'
    // param3 = 'z'
}
```

**Rest**

> The rest parameter allows us to pass an indefinite number of parameters to a function and access them in an array.

Rest works in a similar way as the spread operator but will iterate over all arguments passed to a function and allow you to access them in array.

```
test(1,2,3,4,5,6)

function test(...args) {
    console.log(args); // [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    // Instead of ar
}
```