# JavaScript Rest operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to learn javascript but having trouble in the spread and rest operators.
Can't understand whats happening here how dose this take in the taxRate parameter like a singel number when we spred the itemsBought parameter

```
function addTaxToPrices (taxRate, ...itemsBought)
    {
        return(itemsBought.map(item => item*taxRate));
    }
    let ShoppingCart=addTaxToPrices(1.1,46,89,35,79);
    console.log(ShoppingCart)
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59792746/how-does-the-spread-rest-operator-in-js-work

Comment: That's just the syntax, whenever you use the rest operator it captures all the extra arguments not captured by a named paramater

Comment: First argument becomes the taxRate, so the value 1.1 . The rest operator will collect all the arguments past the first one into an array. So itemsBought becomes [46,89,35,79] .

Comment: @Shilly thanks i get now
So the rest operator is just a spread operator used to at time of declaration of an array that we don't know the size-of  ?Thanks a bunch!!!!

Answer (score 0):

for my understanding it is nearly the same than if you do:

```
function addTaxToPrices (taxRate, itemsBought)
    {
        return(itemsBought.map(item => item*taxRate));
    }
itemsBought = [46,89,35,79]
let ShoppingCart=addTaxToPrices(1.1,itemsBought);
console.log(ShoppingCart)
```