# SPREAD operator in array destructuring

Tags: javascript

In the below example, unmapped array items must be mapped to rest parameter in the left hand side, but for some reason the output is different,

```
var planets = ["Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn"];
var [first, second, ...rest] = ["Mercury", "Earth", ...planets, "Saturn"];

console.log(first); //Output: Mercury
console.log(second); //Output: Earth
```

Now for the below, expected output is,

```
console.log(rest); //Output: ["Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn"]
```

But the actual output is,

```
console.log(rest); //Output: "Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn", "Saturn"
```

Source:https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/array-destructuring-in-es6-30e398f21d10/

Whats happening here?

Comment: That's now how spread syntax and rest syntax works,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spread Syntax ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you spread planet into your your second array, you're putting all the elemtns from the `planets` array into the second array, so:

```
["Mercury", "Earth", ...planets, "Saturn"];
```

... evaluates to:

```
["Mercury", "Earth", "Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn", "Saturn"];
```

you then destructure the first and second elements from this array giving you `"Mercury"` and `"Earth"`. You then use the rest pattern `...rest` to retrieve the remaining elements (ie elements from index 2 and onwards) and store them in the array named `rest`. Thus, your `rest` array contains all the elements from the array above, excluding the first and second elements:

```
["Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn", "Saturn"]
```

To do get your expected output, you can destucture the first array, by ignoring the first two elements:

```js
const [,,...rest] = ["Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn"];
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: @Nag I see, no worries

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

> The Set object lets you store unique values

```js
var planets = ["Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn"];
var [first, second, ...rest] = new Set(["Mercury", "Earth", ...planets, "Saturn"]);

console.log(first);
console.log(second);

console.log(rest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can spread selectively. When you spread `...planets` it copies all the values from planets array to the array you're creating.

You can simply use slice before spreading.

```js
var planets = ["Mercury", "Earth", "Venus", "Mars", "Pluto", "Saturn"];
var [first, second, ...rest] = ["Mercury", "Earth", ...planets.slice(2, planets.length - 1), "Saturn"];

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
console.log(rest)
```

Comment: FYI. `Saturn` appears twice

Comment: @User863 we can avoid that just simply using second argument of slice