# How to use .splice() property at React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, splice

I'm new at Reactjs and in this case, I'm trying to show a list of operations. I need to show only the LAST 10 operations of the list and I'm trying to do this using `.splice()` on the array. I tried a lot but couldn´t make it work.
I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: list is not iterable.

Any idea how to do this?

This is my component code so far:

```
export default function ListOperations() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const list = useSelector((state) => state.operations);
  const [list, setList] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/operation");

      dispatch({
        type: "LIST_OPERATIONS",
        list: response.data,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      swal("Error", e.message, "error");
    }
  }, []);

  const currentListCopy = [...list];

  if (currentListCopy >= 10) {
    currentListCopy.splice(10);
    setList(currentListCopy);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>OPERATIONS HISTORY:</h2>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {list.map((oneOperation) =>
            oneOperation ? (
              <tr key={oneOperation.id}>
                <td>{oneOperation.id}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.reason}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.amount}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.date}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.type}</td>
              </tr>
            ) : null
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> UPDATED VERSION:

```
export default function ListOperations(){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const storeList = useSelector((state) => state.operations);
    const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(async () => {
        try{
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/operation');

            dispatch({
                type: 'LIST_OPERATIONS',
                list: response.data
            })

            if(Array.isArray(storeList) && storeList.length){
                const currentListCopy = [...storeList];
                if(currentListCopy.length >= 10){
                    currentListCopy.splice(10);
                    setList(currentListCopy);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            swal("Error", e.message, "error");
        }
    }, [storeList]);
```

Comment: The infinite loop is caused by providing the `storeList` as dependency to the same `useEffect` hook, which is updating the same state. You should use two `useEffect` hooks. One to update the state on component rendering with empty dependency and the other `useEffect` one with `storeList` as dependency. I'm adding the whole code at the end of the answer.

Comment: Glad, i was able to help. 

Also, if you find some answer useful to your question, you can accept it :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, which are causing the error and also, if the error is fixed, the fetched results will not be shown in the application.

**Issue 1**

```
const [list, setList] = React.useState({});
```

In the above code, you're initializing state as an object, which is causing the error `list is not iterable`, in the below code, when you're trying to use the [spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6) operator to create an array of `state object`.

```
const currentListCopy = [...list];
```

**Fix**

You can fix this issue by initialing the `list` state as an empty array.

```
const [list, setList] = React.useState({});
```

**Issue 2**

The second issue is you're dispatching an action in the `useEffect` hook, but not getting the updated state from the store, since this line `// const list = useSelector((state) => state.operations);` is commented out. Since you're not fetching any state from store also nor updating the local state `list`, you'll not see any changes in the map function, as its empty, even though some data is being returned from the network in the API call.

**Fix**

If you wish to use the state from the store to update the local store, than you've to uncomment this line `// const list = useSelector((state) => state.operations)`  and rename list to something else.

Also you need to move your `splice` code to the `useEffect` hook, so, whenever the `list` updated in the global state, your local state also updated accordingly.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(list) && list.length) { // assuming list is the global state and we need to ensure the list is valid array with some indexes in it.
      const currentListCopy = [...list];
      if(currentListCopy.length >= 10) { // as above answer point out
        currentListCopy.splice(10);
        setList(currentListCopy)
      }
    }
 }, [list]); // added list as a dependency to run the hook on any change in the list
```

Also, as above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69330815/8876221) point out, you should avoid async functions in the  `useEffect`.

**Update**

the complete code

```js
export default function ListOperations() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const storeList = useSelector((state) => state.operations);
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/operation");

      dispatch({
        type: "LIST_OPERATIONS",
        list: response.data,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      swal("Error", e.message, "error");
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(storeList) && storeList.length) {
      const currentListCopy = [...storeList];
      if(currentListCopy.length >= 10) {
        currentListCopy.splice(10);
        setList(currentListCopy)
      }
    }
 }, [storeList]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>OPERATIONS HISTORY:</h2>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {list.map((oneOperation) =>
            oneOperation ? (
              <tr key={oneOperation.id}>
                <td>{oneOperation.id}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.reason}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.amount}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.date}</td>
                <td>{oneOperation.type}</td>
              </tr>
            ) : null
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The component now shows only the last 10 operations as i needed but I've checked in console the arrays "list" (from global state) and "currentListCopy" and it is responding with infinite loops

Comment: Could you please share the whole code of the file? Maybe, add in the question, under the original text with a heading. `Updated version`

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(currentListCopy >= 10){
    currentListCopy.splice(10);
    setList(currentListCopy)
}
```

you're missing "length" :

```js
if(currentListCopy.length >= 10){
    currentListCopy.splice(10);
    setList(currentListCopy)
}
```

also, you shouldn't use promise inside useEffect
https://dev.to/danialdezfouli/what-s-wrong-with-the-async-function-in-useeffect-4jne