# Why is my for loop not returning the lowest value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

so I have this code here and the value i want to receive froma this array [2,1,2,0,1] is 1, i Know how to make it skip 0 but for some reason it accepts 2 as the lowest value, can anyone explain to me why and find a way to deal with it?

```
    let lowestP = 100000000000000000000000000
    let highestP = 0
    let startWorking = 0
    
    for(let i = 0; i < prices.length;i++){
    
      if(lowestP > prices[i] && prices[i] > 0){
        lowestP = prices[i]

  }if(highestP<prices[i]){
        highestP = prices[i]
      }
      if(prices.indexOf(lowestP) > prices.indexOf(highestP)){
        highestP = 0
        continue
    
      }
   startWorking = highestP - lowestP
      
    }return startWorking
};
```

I did some console logging and it seems like the first 2 in [2,1,2,0,1] is the problem, still i didnt find the solution

Comment: What is your initial value of `lowestP` ?

Comment: lowestP = 100000000000000000000000000

Comment: Is there a reason why you don’t use `Math.min` and `Math.max`?

Comment: I forgot about those, I'm still a beginner

Comment: `Math.min` will return 0 in your case.

Comment: It is not entirely clear how you want to determine `highestP`. Is that the largest value in the array after the first occurrence of the lowest value (that is not `0`)?

Comment: yes, that's what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
let prices = [2, 1, 2, 0, 1];
let lowestP = 999999999999999;

prices.forEach((price, index) =>
  price > 0 && lowestP > price ? (lowestP = prices[index]) : null
);
```

Comment: Such kind of constructs should be avoided as they are hard to read and understand.

Comment: It's a simple ternary, where do you see the hardness?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the index of the lowest and highest p, prices.indexOf(highestP), for the second 2 returns index of the first 2 in the prices list.

```
var maxProfit = function (prices)
{
    let lowestP = 100000000000000000000000000
    let highestP = 0
    let startWorking = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
        if (lowestP > prices[i] && prices[i] > 0) {
            lowestP = prices[i]
            index_lowest = i
        }
        if (highestP < prices[i]) {
            highestP = prices[i]
            index_highest = i
        }
        if (index_lowest > index_highest) {
            highestP = 0
            continue
        }
        startWorking = highestP - lowestP
    }
    return startWorking
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to make structure your code so that it is self-documentary.

If you e.g. first want to filter your array so that certain values don't exist then use `filter`, if you search the minimum or maximum, then use the corresponding functions.

To pass the filtered array to the `Math.min` function you can use the [Spread Syntax (`...`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6)

```js
let prices = [2, 1, 2, 0, 1]
prices = prices.filter(value => value > 0);

if (prices.length === 0) {
  console.error('no prices larger then 0')
} else {
  let lowestP = Math.min(...prices);
  console.log(lowestP)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is totally fine (what you displayed in your inquiry).
In any case, I think you need to show more piece of your code to distinguish issue. How are you handling 0 value in array? there might be some issue. But just for reference attaching piece of code to finding minimum value from array.

```html
   public static int getMaxValue(int[] numbers){
  int maxValue = numbers[0];
  for(int i=1;i < numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i] > maxValue){
      maxValue = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  return maxValue;
}
public static int getMinValue(int[] numbers){
  int minValue = numbers[0];
  for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i] < minValue){
      minValue = numbers[i];
    }
  }
  return minValue;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that im writing it in javascript + here is the code `var maxProfit = function(prices) {
    let lowestP = 100000000000000000000000000
    let highestP = 0
    let startWorking = 0
    
    for(let i = 0; i < prices.length;i++){
    
      if(lowestP > prices[i] && prices[i] > 0){
        lowestP = prices[i]

  }if(highestP<prices[i]){
        highestP = prices[i]
      }
      if(prices.indexOf(lowestP) > prices.indexOf(highestP)){
        highestP = 0
        continue
    
      }
   startWorking = highestP - lowestP
      
    }return startWorking
};`