# How to sort in ascending order a table using a slice of each cell's textContent

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, dom-events

so im trying to creat a function that sorts a table based on the 1st cell of each row (excluding the 1st row)
the text value of the elements is the value of an input from a form and it has to be (AA111) two letters and 3 numbers

it has to switch the entire row (with all its cells) based on the value of the number(in this expl 111) of the textContent(in this expl AA111) of the 1st cell with the row above (if this one has a greater value)

AAAH and this table can expand each time as it has a button calling a function that adds a new row with different values everytime this button is clicked

i tried to collect each row with a for loop and then collect the value of the 1st cell then do a `.slice(2);`
then transform it into a number with `Number()`but it seems to be a problem with it as it's not working
here's my function

```js
function Sort() {
  let table = document.getElementById('add'); //table id
  let row = table.rows;
  let switching = true;
  let tmp0 = new Array();
  tmp0.length = row.length;
  let tmp1 = new Array();
  tmp1.length = row.length;
  let tmp2 = new Array();
  tmp2.length = row.length;
  let ech;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < row.length - 1; i++) {
      tmp0[i] = row[i].cells[0].innerText; /* collecting the intire content from the 1st cell of each row then         turning it into a number*/
      tmp1[i] = tmp0[i].slice(2);
      tmp2[i] = Number(tmp1[i]);
      if (tmp2[i] > tmp2[i + 1]) // swicthing the values if the 1st one is greater
      {
        ech = row[i].innerHTML;
        row[i].innerHTML = row[i + 1].innerHTML;
        row[i + 1].innerHTML = ech;
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i tried to remove the `if` condition and `.slice` part to try and see where the problem is

```js
function Sort() {
  let table = document.getElementById('add');
  let switching = true;
  let row = table.rows;
  while (switching) {
    switching = false;
    for (var i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
      ech = row[i].innerHTML;
      row[i].innerHTML = row[i + 1].innerHTML;
      row[i + 1].innerHTML = ech;
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

and this `while` loop is actually working as it did change the values of the cells each time i pressed the button that i linked this function with

so is it the way that i collected the values that is wrong or is it the use of slice or just everything

please help me see the mistake

Comment: btw, you could create a new array with length directly: `let tmp0 = Array(row.length);`

Comment: AAH thankss didn t know bout this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the table rows to an array, and use the built-in `sort()` method with a comparison function that extracts the slice you want.

Then you can update the table to contain the rows in the sorted order.

```js
function Sort() {
  let table = document.getElementById('add'); //table id
  let rows = [...table.rows].slice(1); // skip header row
  rows.sort((row1, row2) => Number(row1.cells[0].innerText.slice(2)) - Number(row2.cells[0].innerText.slice(2)));
  rows.forEach(row => table.appendChild(row)); // Add back in new order
}
```

```html
<table id="add">
<tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th></tr>
<tr><td>AB321</td><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>XX12</td><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>ZX123</td><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>

<button onclick="Sort()">
Click to sort
</button>
```

Comment: No need to remove the original row, since an element only can be at one place: It will be removed automatically.

Comment: i  think i get it... after the sustraction of both parametres the rows will be sorted and then the `forEach` will make each row a child of the table right? but what does the `[...  ]`mean ?by doing so will the `table.rows` be transformed into an array so the 1st element would be something like `"<tr><th></th>...</tr>"` then the slice(1) would skip it? i copied it into my code but it doesn t seem to work also thank you

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6 for an explanation of JavaScript spread syntax with `...`.

Comment: I forgot to use `.innerText` to get the text of the cell. I've updated and tested it.