# Spread Operator Issue with Float and Boolean Variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

`Spread Operator` throws error for float and boolean variable. Is there any specific reason for getting error on float and boolean variable.

```
// Works, Array Variable
'use strict';

let aVal = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(...aVal);

// Works, String Variable
'use strict';

let sVal = 'String';
console.log(...sVal);

// throws error, Integer Variable
'use strict';

let iVal = 1234567890;
console.log(...iVal);

// throws error, Float Variable
'use strict';

let fVal = 99.45;
console.log(...fVal);

// throws error, Boolean Variable
'use strict';

let bVal = true;
console.log(...bVal);
```

Comment: Yes, because you can't iterate over them. What result would you expect from spreading a float for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any specific reason for getting error on float and boolean variable.

Yes: Spread syntax (it isn't an operator) only works with [*iterable*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-iterable-interface) objects (objects that implement iteration). Numbers and booleans are not iterable. Things like arrays and maps and sets are iterable.

`console.log(...aVal);` asks the JavaScript engine to iterate through `aVal` and then call `console.log` with each iterated value as a discrete argument. That is, it asks javaScript to "spread out" that iterable.

Here's an example of spread with an iterable (in this case, an array):

```js
function foo(a, b, c, d) {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
}
let a = ["the", "answer", "is", 42];
foo(...a);
```

Note how the entries in `a` are "spread out" into discrete (separate) arguments for `foo`.

---

The examples below were from earlier when your question was asking about "the rest operator" by mistake. Just for completeness:

Here's an example of rest syntax (also not an operator) in a function signature:

```js
function foo(...args) {
  console.log(`I got ${args.length} args`);
}
foo('a', 'b', 'c');
```

...and rest syntax in a destructuring assignment:

```js
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let [ x, y, ...z ] = a;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, it's syntax, not an operator.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, what is difference by calling as spread syntax when compare to spread operator !!

Comment: You meant to say. below pages need to be corrected ?
http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: @Venkatraman: Yup. There is no "spread operator." In fact, there can't be: No operator could do what spread syntax does. People use the term casually, but [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html) doesn't, for good reason. Operators take operands and produce a resulting value. There's no value `...` could produce in `foo(...array)` that would then allow `foo` to be called with discrete arguments. (The spec isn't shy about using the word "operator" for things that actually are operators.)

Comment: @Venkatraman: It might have been possible to define a meta-value for specification purposes and then call it an operator, but they didn't go that way, and [it leads to real-world differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019557/using-spread-operator-multiple-times-in-javascript).

Comment: You mean to say, we have to call it as Spread syntax. can we change it in MDN ?

Comment: @Venkatraman: Of course we can, MDN is community-edited. I don't have time to right now, but you're right we should.

Comment: Nice. Will do. I accept your answer. hope you like my observation on this topic as a question.

Comment: @Venkatraman: I usually use terms depending on the context: spread parameter `foo(...bar)`, spread element `[...foo]`, rest argument `function(...bar) {}`, rest element (destructuring) `[...bar] = foo;`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah. "Syntax" for the general case, but then more specific for the specific case.