# Use spread operator on objects array?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Say I have an Object with an array on it like so `someObj.myArray.someFunc`, how do you use the spread operator on it?

I'v tried `myObj....myArray.someFunc()` , `myObj[...myArray].someFunc` and

`myArray = myObj.myArray` `...myArray.someFunc`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `...` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019557/using-spread-operator-multiple-times-in-javascript/35020522#35020522) [an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `someFunc` is method of `Array.prototype` (e.g. forEach, map, ...):

```
[...myObj.myArray].someFunc;
```

However, if `someFunc` is method of object in array, you can iterate array and just call it. E.g.:

```
myObj.myArray.forEach(item => item.someFunc());
```

Comment: oh shoot, I wasn't thinking clearly. I won't be able to use the spread operator  as someFunc is defined on the objects in the array