# Using spread operator on array of object to access elements

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

How to use the spread operator to access element in my array of object ?

```js
const array = [{ obj: 1},{ obj: 2}]

console.log([...array].obj)
// Output undefined 

console.log([...array.obj])
// Output Uncaught TypeError
```

I've seen this post [Use spread operator on objects array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406663/use-spread-operator-on-objects-array) which is quite similar but they do not try to access elements.

So is it possible to use spread operator on array of object to access elements ? If so how ?

Comment: What are you expecting as output? Both `1` and `2`?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: `[...array]` -> clones `array` into a new array. You take the `.obj` property of that array. Arrays don't have an `.obj` property, so you get undefined. `[...array.obj]` -> spread `array.obj` as an array. Since arrays don't have an `.obj` property, you're doing an array spread of `undefined`. That causes an error.

Comment: Long story shorts, you can't use the spread operator like that in JS.

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for `map`

What you need is `array.map(element => element.obj)`

Here's what's wrong with your attempts:

- `console.log([...array].obj)`: You're spreading the `array` into a new array, and then you're logging the `obj` property of the new array, which is `undefined`, as expected
- `console.log([...array.obj])`: You're trying to spread the `obj` property of `array`, which is also `undefined`, meaning you're trying to spread `undefined`, which throws you an error

Comment: Nop sorry, my question is really what is it. I know how to browse an object using function like map, forEach, for...  But that's not my question. Thanks though

Comment: Thanks again for you edit and help.  So no way to use the spread syntax to access my elements ? I must use a function ?

Comment: @user15873596 spreading doesn't work like mapping at all. So...no, you cannot make it work like mapping.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, that was what I was looking for :)

Comment: @user15873596 A spread operator is just like what it says, it's used to spread an array into a new array, or an object key-value pairs into a new object, as is. You can't modify stuff using this operator

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, **no**.

We cannot use spread operator on array of object to access elements.

As [@VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) said  in a comment

> Spreading doesn't work like mapping at all. So...no, you cannot make
> it work like mapping