# Why can't we use the spread operator within Array.map() and what are the alternative to flatten array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, spread-syntax

Here is what I tried:

```
let a = [[1,2], [3,4]];

a.map(val => ...val)
// => SyntaxError: expected expression, got '...'
// Expected output: [1,2,3,4]
```

I tried with explicit `return` statement and surrounding value with parenthesis but none worked...

I just wonder if there is a simple way to return "spreaded array" ?

Edit: Now I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019557/using-spread-operator-multiple-times-in-javascript) which has got precision on how spread operator works although in doesn't really answer the question on how to "flatten" an array (I modified the title of the question).

Comment: Spreading creates multiple values – a function in JavaScript can only return one value

Comment: You should see `Array.prototype.flat()`.

Comment: You can do `[].concat(...a)`

Comment: @PatrickHund No, spreading doesn't "create" any values, it's not an expression on its own. Spread syntax is part of only array literal and function call syntax where it has a specific meaning, and the three dots are simply *syntactically* invalid elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe I expressed my comment incorrectly. I know what spread syntax is and how it works. Never mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `a.flatMap(x=>x);` to flat array and map elements or `flat` (with no mapping)

```
a.flat();
```

```js
let a = [[1,2], [3,4]];

let r=a.flat();

console.log(r);
```

In `flat` arg you can set deep-level of flatting - setting `Infinity` will flat any nested array

```js
let a = [[1,2,[3,4,[5,[6]]]], [[7,[8]],9]];

let r=a.flat(Infinity);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: I like this new feature of JS

Answer (score 7):

This isn't valid syntax, for this to work you need to spread ("unpack" the contents of) your array into a container of some sort (such as an array). However, if you were to do something like:

```
a.map(val => [...val])
```

you would *not* be doing much with your array, and instead, you would end up with copies of the same array. Thus, you can use different methods other than `.map` such as `.reduce` or `.flatMap`/`.flat` to achieve your desired output:

Using `.reduce` with the spread syntax:

```js
let a = [[1,2], [3,4]];

let res = a.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, ...val], []);
console.log(res)
```

Using `.flatMap()`:

```js
let a = [[1,2], [3,4]];

let res = a.flatMap(val => val); // map the contents (without the holding array) [[1, 2], [3, 4]] -> [1, 2, [3, 4]] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
console.log(res)
```

`.flatMap()` is, however, useless here, and thus using `.flat()` would simply suffice:

```js
let a = [[1,2], [3,4]];

let res = a.flat();
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

As written in comments, functions can only return **one** value.

But there is a simple trick what you can use:

```
let a = [[1,2], [3,4]];

a.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b),[])
// Expected output: [1,2,3,4]
```