# Flatten arguments into one dimensional array using the rest parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce, flatten

I've developed the following code (http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/KrkdPj) when trying to flatten a multidimensional array into a one-dimensional array.

For example,

```
flattenArray([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7])
// should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]


// Flatten an array
function flattenArray(input) {
  return input.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (Array.isArray(curr)) {return prev.concat(flattenArray(curr));}
    else {return prev.concat(curr);}
  }, []);
}

console.log(  flattenArray([1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7])  );
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

The above seems to work OK.

Now, I've been asked to make another function that instead of an array will achieve the same result for a mix of numbers and arrays.

For example,

```
flattenMix(1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7);
// should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I've slightly modified the above by adding the rest parameter so that the function can accept an arbitrary number of arguments. However I'm getting a `maximum call stack` error. Would you know what the problem is with the function below?

```
// Flatten arguments (arbitrary length) consisting of a mix of numbers and arrays
function flattenMix(...input) {
  return input.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (Array.isArray(curr)) {return prev.concat(flattenMix(curr));}
    else {return prev.concat(curr);}
  }, []);
}

console.log(  flattenMix(1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7)  ); // should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**UPDATE 1**

The answer and suggestions below have indicated that I should be using the `...` spread operator in the recursive call `flattenMix(...curr)`. In this way when the `curr` is an array (as tested) then the containing elements of the `curr` would be passed in to the `flattenMix` function (instead of the `curr` array).

Comment: Your if statement must be resolving to true all the time. Use a tool (like Chrome Dev Tools) and step through the code to find out why this is.

Comment: Try `prev.concat(flattenMix(...curr));` - but follow evolutionxbox's advice, it will help you immensely with debugging.

Comment: @le_m, your suggestion has indeed fixed the issue. If you add it as an answer, I would accept it as an solution.

Comment: @PiotrBerebecki I am on mobile, so writing an answer is bothersome (no stack snippets etc). Better accept Nina's answer, hers is equally correct.

Comment: Related: [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33898512).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just use the spread operator.

```js
function flattenMix(...input) {
    return input.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        if (Array.isArray(curr)) {
            return prev.concat(flattenMix(...curr));
            //                            ^^^^^^^
        } else {
            return prev.concat(curr);
        }
    }, []);
}

console.log(flattenMix(1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7));
```

Comment: @Piotr Just to clarify it: `...` in a function declaration is called `rest` operator. Used within a function call it is called `spread` operator and causes the exact opposite of `rest`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, easy. Your first method can already deal with an array and since `arguments` is basically an array we can just add an extra line.

```js
// Flatten an array
function flattenArray(input) {
  return input.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    if (Array.isArray(curr)) {
      return prev.concat(flattenArray(curr));
    } else {
      return prev.concat(curr);
    }
  }, []);
}

function flattenMix() {
  return flattenArray([].slice.call(arguments));
}

console.log(flattenMix(1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7));
```

Comment: The rest operator is exactly the replacement of `arguments` in ES2015.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you send an array as first argument in recursion instead of array items.
You can use `flatten.apply(null, arr)` or `flatten(...arr)`:

```js
// Flatten arguments (arbitrary length) consisting of a mix of numbers and arrays

function flatten(...input) {
  return input.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(
      Array.isArray(curr) ? flatten(...curr) : curr
    );
  }, []);
}

console.log(flatten(1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7)); // should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

### Do it the fun way

If you convert an array of array to string this would flatten the array for you and the only thing you should do is to convert string numbers to `Number`.

```js
function flattenArgs() {
  return Array.from(arguments).toString()
    .split(',').map(Number);
}

console.log(flattenArgs(1, [2, 3], 4, [5, [6]], 7));
```

Comment: @nnnnnn What you mean by that? I don't get it.

Comment: I mean that you've not explained why the OP's code doesn't work, you've given a completely different solution.

Comment: That's much better as your little hack. Please replace `apply` with the spread operator though, because this is exactly the purpose of `spread`.

Comment: @LUH3417 I've explained both are applicable. BTW for fun of modern JS I did it too.

Comment: As you know `apply` was originally introduced to set the implicit `this` parameter directly (and to spread the items of an array to the given function of course). The spread operator...just spreads and thus fits better.

Comment: @LUH3417 That was a good point. I mentioned `apply` just because of it's compatibility with older browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new method Array.flat()

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr2.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr3.flat(2);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat