# What does three dots do in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const peopleList = this.state.people.map( x => {

    return <Person key={x.name} {...x} />
})
```

What does "{...x} " this code mean?

Comment: for the next time, `...` is called ellipsis. it will make googling it easier.  ;)

Comment: See also [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33898512).

Answer (score 30):

This is a spread operator syntax in react.

From the **[MDN DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**:

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where
> multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for
> array literals) or multiple variables (for destructuring assignment)
> are expected.

In your case `<Person key={x.name} {...x} />` It means that send the entire object or properties contained with `x` as it looks as props to the `Person Component`

For example if

```
var x = {
     name: "Hello",
     last_name: "World"

}
```

Then if you do `<Person key={x.name} {...x} />`

The above will be equivalent of

```
<Person key={x.name} name={x.name} last_name={x.last_name}/>
```

> The order in which the spread syntax is used along with the props is also significant.

Consider a case where you pass the props to a component like

```
var data = {
     name: 'abc',
     age: '25',
     college: 'lmit'
}
```

and if you use the spread operator syntax like

```
 <Person key={x.name} name='xyz' {...data} />
```

Then the prop `name='xyz'` is overwritten by the key:value pair resolved from data. So the final `Person` component call will look like

```
 <Person key={x.name} name='abc' age= '25' college= 'lmit' />
```

However when you write it like

```
 <Person key={x.name}  {...data} name='xyz' />
```

Then the prop `name='abc'` that is resolved from data is overwritten by `name='xyz'` that is passed explicitly to `Person`. So the final `Person` Component call will look like

```
  <Person key={x.name} name='xyz' age= '25' college= 'lmit' />
```

Comment: I never used spread operators before. I should .

Comment: @Ved Yeah sometimes it makes the code really short and is very useful

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes We get used to of using general syntax.. Power of ES6 still need to be explored more.

Comment: very well explained....Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That is the spread operator. It was introduced in ES2015. It takes all the properties of x and distributes them to the element.

`{...x}` means take all properties assigned to the object x, then assign them to `<Person />`

You can read more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator