# What in JavaScript ES6, does `return { ...state, all: action.payload.data }` with that last additional property do?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Short question is: what does the line

```
return { ...state, all: action.payload.data };
```

do? (particularly with the `all:` part).

If you don't use ES6, and `state` has

1. 2 properties like below
2. 10 properties instead of 2
3. unknown number of properties

then how would it be written?

---

**Details:** it is part of React / Redux. In a reducer function, given a previous state and action, it does:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  all: [],
  post: null
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return { ...state, all: action.payload.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can check http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048953/what-does-the-three-dots-in-react-do

Comment: That's not ES6.

Comment: You mean it is ES5 or?

Answer (score 4):

Technically, this is the same as calling:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {all: action.payload.data});
```

It means that the resulting object:

1. is not the original object
2. it contains all properties from `state`
3. it contains a new value for property `all`.

Answer (score 1):

What `return { ...state, all: action.payload.data };` does is to destructure the state to obtain all the properties in it and then return the object by modifying all only the object with key `all`

suppose in your case

```
state={
  all: [],
  post: null
};
```

then

`...state` will return you `all:[], post:null` as separate values. So with `{ ...state, all: action.payload.data }` you are setting the value of `all` to be `action.payload.data` and returning the entire values wrapped as an object. In your case if `action.payload.data = ["hello", "world"]`, it will return

```
{
    all: ["hello", "world"],
    post: null
}
```