# use a single handler for multiple inputs onChange events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have bunch of inputs and I do not want to have multiple handlers like

`handleInput1(){}`,`handleInput2(){}` and so on.

But I have difficulties producing below array of object

```
[{
  name: 3,
  value: 1000
},{
  name: 5,
  value: 1000
}]
```

how can I by using listen to only one handler and use setState in react?

http://jsbin.com/godesacici/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it the follwoing way by distinguishing the different inputs by the name attribute and storing the result in the state

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      result: []
    }
  }
  handleInput(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value);
      var result = [...this.state.result];
      var idx = result.map(function(val){ return val.name}).indexOf(e.target.name);
      if(idx > -1) {
          result[idx].value=e.target.value;
      } else {
        result.push({name: e.target.name, value:e.target.value});
      }
       this.setState({result})
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state.result);
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
      <div><input type="number" name="4" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)}/></div>
      <div><input type="number" name="3" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)}/></div>
      <div><input type="number" name="5" onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)}/></div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hatotemine/1/edit?js,console,output)**

Comment: wow look so complicated, I was expecting something like splice or lodash find.

Comment: what is wrong with var result = this.state.result? why need to use `...` here?

Comment: This doesnt require any dependency for you, and I am sure this is not complicated.

Comment: ok I slowly getting it now but why need ... getting state of result to var result?

Comment: You cannot directly modify the state so you are using spread operator to get the state value to the local variable that we can modify and then setting that to state

Comment: See this for what `...` mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs/42811937#42811937

Comment: this worked great but it's a pain if I have initial state, it's array of object, how am I going to construct my jsx?

Comment: This is the output that you mentioned in your question right, how do you want to construct your jsx and for what

Answer (score 0):

So you can be explicit and bind the key string onto a single handler function like so:

```
_handleInput(key, val) {
  let { ..state } = this.state;
  state[key] = val;
  this.setState(state);
}
render() {
  return <div>
           <input
            onChange={this.handleInput.bind(null, key1)}
            value={this.state.key1} />
           <input
            onChange={this.handleInput.bind(null, key2)}
            value={this.state.key2} />
         </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `name` property to input, and get `target.name` like this:

```
_handleInput(event) {
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({[name] : value});
}

<input
    onChange={this._handleInput}
    value={this.state.key1} 
    name="key1"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your state model to have a key per form element and use some nice-to-haves like arrow functions to capture variable scope in a cleaner syntax, you can simplify things:

```js
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "3": {},
      "4": {},
      "5": {}
    }
  }

  handleInput(name, value) {
    this.setState({
      [name]: {
        name: name,
        value: value
      }
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.state); 
  }

  render() {
    return (      
      <div>
      <div><input type="number" value={this.state["3"].value} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(3, e.target.value)}/></div>
      <div><input type="number" value={this.state["4"].value} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(4, e.target.value)}/></div>
      <div><input type="number" value={this.state["5"].value} onChange={(e) => this.handleInput(5, e.target.value)}/></div>
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick()}>submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent name="Joe Schmoe"/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

Having your state be an array of values not keyed by anything will force you to search through the state and replace it (as some of the other answers have shown).

It's usually a better idea to simplify things to improve readability and comprehension

Recall that React state is additive, so calling `setState` with just a partial state change will merge it with the existing state.  You will only get this benefit if you're keying your data in the state.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an an array you want to modify you can use array indices. Suppose the initial state is this.

```
this.state = {
  array: [{
    name: 3,
    value: 1000
  },{
    name: 5,
    value: 1000
  }]
}
```

Then the inputs can be like this (for the one with name 3 which has index 0)

```
<input value={this.state.array[0].value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,0)}/>
```

So the value it will display is for the 1st element in the array (with index 0) and the `handleChange` binds to the `event` as well as pass the index 0.

```
handleChange(index,event){
this.setState((prevState) => ({array:[  
        ...prevState.array.slice(0, index),
        Object.assign({},prevState.array[index],{value:event.target.value}),
        ...prevState.array.slice(index + 1)
        ]}))
}
```

Ok so this might seem a little complicate but let me try to explain here. So the `handleChange` method takes two parameters - the `event` corresponding to the input text and the `index` which is the array index of the element in the state array (0 in our example). So in `this.setState` we have taken the `prevState` and used a bit of splicing. `...prevState.array.slice(0,index)` corresponds to all elements of the array before the one we are modifying. `...prevState.slice(index+1)` corresponds to all those after. So we take these two sets and join them with the modified element in between. The `Object.assign()` corresponds to the modified element. What it is doing is taking the `prevState.array[index]` which is the element we are modifying and setting it's `value` to `event.target.value` corresponding to the text.

Comment: `<input value={this.state.array[0].value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,0)}/>` how can you assume the first item has the name 3?

Comment: Ok, so the elements aren't fixed in the array? If the elements are randomized and the inputs are generated from the array you can do something like `<input placeholder={this.state.array[0].name} value={this.state.array[0].value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,0)}/> ` so people will have an idea about which input corresponds to which name. I was assuming you set the initial state yourself.