# do we have to use multiple state in react to access multiple components when clicked

Tags: reactjs

I want to render a component when i clicked a button to do this I added a state to remember click .There a four different buttons which render four different components do I have to add state for each and every button ? is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you include your code in your question? Edit your post and paste the code in.

Comment: this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714596/is-there-a-neater-way-to-connect-an-input-field-to-a-state-property-in-react-tha/43714677#43714677 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671680/use-a-single-handler-for-multiple-inputs-onchange-events/43671789#43671789

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do it.Say for each button you have 4 functions defined

```
    a:function()
    {

    this.setState({
    flag:a,
value:"hii"

    })
    }



 b:function()
    {

    this.setState({
   flag:b

    })
    }
c:function()
{

this.setState({
flag:c

})
}

d:function()
{

this.setState({
flag:d

})
}
```

now you can send this state as props to your 4 components as

```
<button onClick="this.a"/>
<button onClick="this.b"/>
<button onClick="this.c"/>
<button onClick="this.d"/>
```

and in render you can call components like
render{

```
if(this.state.flag==='a')
return <ComponentA finalstate={this.state.value}/>
....follow if else control structure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a parent component. In this parent component should be all the child components you want to show when you click the button. Then in the parent component, you have a state property (e.g. activePage), then you set it to a string representating the page name (e.g. activePage="page1").

In your parents render function, you can now create a switch statement, which checks which component it should render (return).

I think this would be a more clean approach than setting the state on the child elements.

Comment: I think he wants to render more than only on element.

Comment: Of course you can add multiple components - just extend the switch statement.