# react doesn't rerender component when props changed

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm changing the class attribute of my props and then i want the component to rerender with the new classes but that doesn't work. I've read about the shouldComponentUpdate method but that method never gets called.

```
  var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
  var React = require('react');

   class Button extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("BUTTON")
    console.log(props);
    var options = props.options;
}
componentWillMount () {
    var defaultFeatureOptionId = this.props.feature.DefaultFeatureOptionId;
    this.props.options.forEach((option) => {
        var classes = "";
        if (option.Description.length > 10) {
            classes = "option-button big-button hidden";
        } else {
            classes = "option-button small-button hidden";
        }
        if (option.Id === defaultFeatureOptionId) {
            classes = classes.replace("hidden", " selected");
            option.selected = true;
        }
        option.class = classes;
    });
}
shouldComponentUpdate(props) {
    console.log("UPDATE");
}
toggleDropdown(option, options) {
    console.log(option);
    console.log(options)

    option.selected = !option.selected;
    options.forEach((opt) => {
        if (option.Id !== opt.Id) {
            opt.class = opt.class.replace("hidden", "");
        }
        else if(option.Id === opt.Id && option.selected) {
            opt.class = opt.class.replace("", "selected");
        } 
    });        
}
render() {
    if (this.props.options) {
        return (<div> {
            this.props.options.map((option) => {
                return <div className={ option.class } key={option.Id}>
                    <div> {option.Description}</div>
                    <img className="option-image" src={option.ImageUrl}></img>
                    <i className="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => this.toggleDropdown(option, this.props.options) }></i>
                    </div>
            })
        }

        </div>
        )
    }     
    else {
        return <div>No options defined</div>
    }
}
 }

 module.exports = Button;
```

I have read a lot of different thing about shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps but there seems to be something else i'm missing.

Comment: according to a blog i read "A re-render can only be triggered if a component’s state has changed. The state can change from a props change, or from a direct setState change. The component gets the updated state and React decides if it should re-render the component. " both the props and state will trigger state change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the props directly, either you call a parent function to change the props that are passed to your component or in your local copy that you createm you can change them. `shouldComponentUpdate` is only called when a state has changed either directly or from the props, you are not doing any of that, only modifying the local copy and hence no change is triggered

Do something like

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var React = require('react');

   class Button extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {options = props.options};
}
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.options !== this.props.options) {
    this.setState({options: nextProps.options})
  }
}
componentWillMount () {
    var defaultFeatureOptionId = this.props.feature.DefaultFeatureOptionId;
    var options = [...this.state.options]
    options.forEach((option) => {
        var classes = "";
        if (option.Description.length > 10) {
            classes = "option-button big-button hidden";
        } else {
            classes = "option-button small-button hidden";
        }
        if (option.Id === defaultFeatureOptionId) {
            classes = classes.replace("hidden", " selected");
            option.selected = true;
        }
        option.class = classes;
    });
    this.setState({options})
}
shouldComponentUpdate(props) {
    console.log("UPDATE");
}
toggleDropdown(index) {

    var options = [...this.state.options];
    var options = options[index];
    option.selected = !option.selected;
    options.forEach((opt) => {
        if (option.Id !== opt.Id) {
            opt.class = opt.class.replace("hidden", "");
        }
        else if(option.Id === opt.Id && option.selected) {
            opt.class = opt.class.replace("", "selected");
        } 
    });   
    this.setState({options})
}
render() {
    if (this.state.options) {
        return (<div> {
            this.state.options.map((option, index) => {
                return <div className={ option.class } key={option.Id}>
                    <div> {option.Description}</div>
                    <img className="option-image" src={option.ImageUrl}></img>
                    <i className="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => this.toggleDropdown(index) }></i>
                    </div>
            })
        }

        </div>
        )
    }     
    else {
        return <div>No options defined</div>
    }
}
 }

 module.exports = Button;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you write this: [...this.state.options] ?

Comment: if i use this.state.options then state will be null. I can use this.setState.options but that is wrong i assume since that is the method used to acctually set the state?

Comment: See this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs/42811937#42811937 to understand what `[...this.state.options]` mean, it creates a duplicate object and wraps within a array in short and is known as spread operator syntax

Comment: even if the constructor gets called first and sets the state. the  var options = [...this.state.options]; in componentWillMount then state will still be null. However this.setState is not. Why is not the state set properly in the constructor?

Comment: never mind. I typed this.setState instead of this.state in the constructor.

Comment: No you should be setting the state in constructor like this.state= {} and not this.setState, it may have happened because initially the props are not avaiable from your parent.