# React.js setState of objects property from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Right now i need to increment/decrement a property value of state's array of  objects. I have tried throwing everything that came to my mind to setState. At times it didnt throw any errors, but wasn't updating the value either Right now i get error message:

> this.state.products[key] is undefined

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    var products = [
        { name: "Motorhead glasses", price: 300, amount: 1 },
        { name: "Judaspriest glasses", price: 499, amount: 1 }
    ]

    this.state = { products: products }
    this.handleMinus = this.handleMinus.bind(this)

}


handleMinus(key) {
    var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    stateCopy.products = stateCopy.products.slice();
    stateCopy.products[key] = Object.assign({}, stateCopy.products[key]);
    stateCopy.products[key].amount += 1;
    this.setState({ [this.state.products[key].amount]: stateCopy });
    console.log(this)
}
```

Comment: how did you implement `handleMinus` in your code? you need to provide that code as well.

Comment: So your key is 0 or 1, in this example, right?

Comment: @RuhulAmin it is implemented but i wont be pasting the whole markup. It works on click, i have fixed context and console.log this works fine

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol propably, but it wouldnt might not be in my actual code

Answer (score 2):

You you clone a state object, you can modify it directly and setback to state

```
handleMinus(key) {
    var stateCopy = [...this.state.products];   /Create a copy of products array using spread operator syntax.
    stateCopy[key].amount += 1;
    this.setState({products : stateCopy });

}
```

If you wanna know what `[...this.state.products]` mean check this answer: [What is the meaning of this syntax "{...x}" in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs/42811937#42811937)

Answer (score 0):

Use this (check the comments):

```
handleMinus(key) {
    var stateCopy = this.state.products.slice();        //create a copy of products array
    stateCopy[key] = Object.assign({}, stateCopy[key])  //create a copy of object at that key
    stateCopy[key].amount += 1;                         //modify the value
    this.setState({products : stateCopy });             //update the state variable
}
```

Your code will also work with a small change, change the way you are using `setState` to update the `state` value, use this:

```
handleMinus(key) {
    var stateCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    stateCopy.products = stateCopy.products.slice();
    stateCopy.products[key] = Object.assign({}, stateCopy.products[key]);
    stateCopy.products[key].amount += 1;
    this.setState(stateCopy);   //use this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re making unnecessary shallow copies of your state.

```
handleMinus(key) {
  const product = this.state.products[key];

  this.setState({
    products: [
      ...this.state.products,

      [key]: Object.assign({}, product, {
        amount: product.amount + 1
      })
    ]
  })
}
```