# how to push an item into an array if it is inside a javascript object [state.lastValue.push is not a function]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm updating some values as a `javascript` `object` inside my `reducer` in `reactjs` like below.

this is the object before the update

```
state = {
  result:1,
  lastval: []
}
```

and this is how I'm going to update it,

```
state = {
      ...state,
      result:state.result + 400,
      lastval: result.lastval.push(20)
    }
```

so this gives me an error of `state.lastValue.push is not a function`. but if I do it like below it is fine,

```
state = {
          ...state,
          result:state.result + 400,
        };
        state.lastval.push(20);
```

this is fine. what is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your state like

```
state = {
  ...state,
  result:state.result + 400,
  lastval: [...state.lastval, 20]
}
```

`lastval: [...state.lastval, 20]` will destructure all the contents inside the `state.lastval` array and add `20` to it and wrap it in an array again.

For more info on what `[...state.lastval]` does read [What is the meaning of this syntax "{...x}" in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs/42811937#42811937)

Answer (score 2):

Reason is, when you write:

```
state = {
   ...state,
   result:state.result + 400,
   lastval: result.lastval.push(20)
}
```

Final status of state will be:

```
state = {
   ...state,
   result:  some value
   lastval: 20
}
```

Means **state.lasteval will become a number**, it will not be an `array`, because **a.push(1) will not return the final array**, it will return the item pushed into `array`.

Write it like this to update the state:

```
state = {
   ...state,
   result: state.result + 400,
   lastval: [...state.lastval, 20]
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [1,2];

let b = [];

b = a.push(3);

console.log('a', a);

console.log('b', b);
```