# Modifying one entry in this.state deletes all other entries in React JS State Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, underscore.js

I am trying to set the state for an object like this

```
vault:{
    main:{
        a:1,
        b:2,
        c:3
    },
    backup:{
        d:4,
        e:5,
        f:6
    }
}
```

when I this.setState({vault:{main:{a:10}}} it deletes all other entries,

I tried using the "underscore library" with the "extend"

How do I get around setting the state of part of a library? seems very strange that this is not possible...

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
this.setState({
    vault:{
        ...this.state.vault,
        main:{
            ...this.state.vault.main,
            a:10
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let newstate = Object.assign({}, this.state);
newstate.main.a = 10;
this.setState({vault:newstate});
```

OR

```
vault:{
    main:{
        a:1,
        b:2,
        c:3
    },
    backup:{
        d:4,
        e:5,
        f:6
    }
}
var new_state = vault;
new_state.main.a =10;
this.setState({vault:new_state});
```

```js
var vault = {
    main:{
        a:1,
        b:2,
        c:3
    },
    backup:{
        d:4,
        e:5,
        f:6
    }
};

let newstate = Object.assign({}, vault);

newstate.main.a = 10;
console.log(newstate);


var new_state = vault;
new_state.main.a =10;
console.log(newstate);
```

Comment: Thank you for this !

So I actually managed to update the object using the simple second option.. i don't know why I couldn't find a reference to this before.... I swear I looked at about 20 different pages.

One thing, it updates my state object, but then when i reference my object to populate my site, it gives me bugs. 

for example when I type "440" in the input, I get "4" in my {this.state.vault.main.a}

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dinesh answer,

You cannot update the nested state directly, you need to create a new object, reset it and then update it back to state.

If you are using ES6 script for your React project, you can make use of spread operator to update the state

Assuming

```
state = {

    vault:{
        main:{
            a:1,
            b:2,
            c:3
        },
        backup:{
            d:4,
            e:5,
            f:6
        }
    }
}
```

you can update the state like

```
var vault = {...this.state.vault}
vault.main.a = 10
this.setState({vault})
```

To know what spread operator does, read **[this DOCS](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html)** and **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs/42811937#42811937)**

Comment: When you say , you type 440 in input and you see 4, how are you passing the input to the function where you are updating state