# Mutating state on React manually, then calling setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying React JS making a simple todo list and part of my code is as follows:

```
changeStatus(e, index) {
    this.state.tasks[index].status = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        tasks: prevState.tasks
    }));
}
```

As React documentation says, we shouldn't change `state` manually, we should call `setState` instead, so, I'm receiving a warning on console saying that, even calling `setState` after the manual changing.

I'm doing so because, for me, is more practical doing that than separating the `task`, doing a `splice` on my array, and calling `setState` with the new values.

Is there a problem with my approach? How would you recommend updating state in a efficient and non-repetitive way?

Comment: [The React docs outline why this is a bad idea:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state) "Never mutate this.state directly, as **calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made**". In other words, there's no guarantee your changes will actually persist if you mutate the state directly.

Comment: As I came from Vue, that wasn't a concern for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, Vue generally seems to be designed with mutation in mind (which is why a lot of people like it over React, even if that's not my personal preference). The reason you have to use `setState` in React is that it allows for optimizations - e.g. if you call `setState` twice in quick succession, they might be merged into one batch update that's carried out all at once. To quote the docs again: "Think of `setState` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component."

Comment: Great. I adopted Vue first because it fits really well for some apps I'm working on. I chose to study React now to use it with React Native Apps and due the market share, although I still prefer Vue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
   changeStatus(e, index) {
      const tmp = { ...this.state };
      tmp.tasks[index].status = e.target.value;
      this.setState(tmp);
   }
```

Comment: simple, easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should not mutate the state directly, to do that create a new object from the state and then update that and set it back to state like

```
changeStatus(e, index) {
    var tasks = {...this.state.tasks}
    tasks[index].status = e.target.value;
    this.setState({tasks});
}
```

In case you are wondering as to what `{...this.state.tasks}` do then check this answer:

[What is the meaning of this syntax "{...x}" in Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-syntax-x-in-reactjs/42811937#42811937)

However you can also make a copy of the state using the `ES5` Object.assign() operator like

```
var tasks = Object.assign({}, this.state.tasks)
```