# Why does redux do `{... store}` in its applyMiddleware implementation?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, middleware

> Although this is about the `applyMiddleware` implementation I accept this being a duplicate of the question referring to the spreading operator as the core of the mental issue is exactly that.

## Preamble:

I don't like magic when it comes to a point where it is actually unclear why things happen. So I was looking in the actual redux implementation.

## What is the problem?

Well I saw this in the implementation of `applyMiddleware`:

[**applyMiddleware.js on github**](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/9e51c170697b9b86e85dffa076549546eff05ab0/src/applyMiddleware.js#L33)

```js
import compose from './compose'

/**
 * Creates a store enhancer that applies middleware to the dispatch method
 * of the Redux store. This is handy for a variety of tasks, such as expressing
 * asynchronous actions in a concise manner, or logging every action payload.
 *
 * See `redux-thunk` package as an example of the Redux middleware.
 *
 * Because middleware is potentially asynchronous, this should be the first
 * store enhancer in the composition chain.
 *
 * Note that each middleware will be given the `dispatch` and `getState` functions
 * as named arguments.
 *
 * @param {...Function} middlewares The middleware chain to be applied.
 * @returns {Function} A store enhancer applying the middleware.
 */
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return (createStore) => (reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) => {
    const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer)
    let dispatch = store.dispatch
    let chain = []

    const middlewareAPI = {
      getState: store.getState,
      dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)
    }
    chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI))
    dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)

    return {
      ...store,
      dispatch
    }
  }
}
```

```
return {
  ...store,
  dispatch
}
```

So it is actually spreading the whole store on the first level of the store object. But we just want to apply middleware and are not actually manipulating the store.

**So why not just do the following?**

```
return {
  store,
  dispatch
}
```

What would be the side-effects of doing `store` over `...store` in this very specific implementation / in the scope of an app using it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning three dots in "{...x}" \[ReactJS\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811882/what-is-the-meaning-three-dots-in-x-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `store` instead of `...store` would completely change the meaning of the expression.

`{store, dispatch}` means the same as: `{store: store, dispatch: dispatch}`

Whereas `{...store, dispatch}` means **expanding/merging** original `store` object with new `dispatch` property.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) about spread syntax.

Comment: Which is totally true and in this case was a temporary mental issue mixing up two different things on my side. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @androidavid You could upvote my answer as well if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I've never had the chance to do a project with `React`, but I did watch a few videos and I know that the idea of the framework is that `store` is **immutable**(*read more about immutability [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/)*), the three dots are called [**Spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and I think that this syntax is used in shorthand instead of [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> **[Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Spread_in_object_literals)**
>
> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 3) adds
>   spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable
>   properties from a provided object onto a new object.
>
> Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now
>   possible using a shorter syntax than [**Object.assign**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

If you change `...store` to `store` you will completely change the behavior of the framework. I don't know what exactly the side effects will be, we need to do some testing :)

I hope this was helpful to you to understand this piece of code better. Good Luck!

Comment: Yup. Totally clear, totally agree. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

`{...store, dispatch}` is the same thing as `Object.assign({}, store, {dispatch: dispatch})`.

`{store, dispatch}` is the same thing as `{store: store, dispatch: dispatch}`.

In case you don't know what `Object.assign` does : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

The result is that if there is some property `foo` that exists on object `store`, on the newly created object `o`, in the first case you access it via `o.foo`, in the second case via `o.store.foo`.

So it makes a real difference ;)

These notations look "magical" until you learn what they do. Then you start feeling they save you a lot of time, let you write DRY and short code.

Comment: The question was already properly and clearly answered 2 times and I evaluated the answers, accepted it and edited my original question. But thanks :)