# Spread element magically turns functions into 'not functions'

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Suppose I have this simple JavaScript function:

```
function returnArray(){
    return [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Further suppose that I then say

```
var test = [0, ...returnArray()];
```

You'd expect test to be equal to [0,1,2,3], and you'd be right. I tried that and of course it works.

Now I have this exercise where I'm suppose to build a function called double that takes an array as a parameter and returns another array that contains all of the original array's values doubled. So if I call double([1,2,3]) I should get [2,4,6]. The constraints of the exercise are that I **must** use *only* array destructuring, recursion, and the rest/spread operators to build my function. No array helpers allowed. So I came up with this:

```
function double(array){
  if (array.length===1) return 2*array[0];
  var [num, ...rest] = array;  
  if (rest.length!=0) return [2*num, ...double(rest)];  
}
```

If I run this function with any array whose size is at least two, I receive an error message saying that double is not a function. If I remove the ... operator before double, magically double is a function again, except that of course the result of double([1,2,3]) is [2,[4,6]], which is not quite the same as [2,4,6].

My first thought was that maybe, for some weird reason, you can't use ... in front of a function, even if the function returns an array, so I tested this hypothesis with my the returnArray() function above, and found out that it works just fine. I have no idea why it breaks down in the exercise. I can only guess recursion might have something to do with it, but I have no clue why it would be so. Can anyone point out what's wrong my my code?

EDIT: Thanks everyone, it was quite a silly mistake! I should have seen it. I added comments to some of your answers.

Comment: You need `return [2*array[0]];`.

Comment: the error I get with that code is `double(...) is not iterable`, not that it's not a function

Comment: Related: [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33898512).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a very strange error message, no question, but the main problem is a logical error in `double`: In two branches of the code, calling `double` results in a non-iterable value (in one case a number, in another `undefined`). But you're always applying spread notation to it. So that fails in those two cases.
The cases are:

1. You're only returning the number, not an array, in the `array.length === 1` case.
2. You're not returning anything in the case where `array.length` is not 1 and `rest.length` is 0, so the result of calling `double` in that case is `undefined`.

You're hitting the case where you try to spread a number first, like this:

```js
function a() {
  return 42;
}
const b = [...a()];
```

For #1, you should be returning an array with one entry. For #2, You should be returning `[]`. So the minimal changes version is:

```js
function double(array) {
  if (array.length === 1) {
    return [2*array[0]];
    //     ^−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−− note
  }
  var [num, ...rest] = array;  
  if (rest.length > 0) {
    return [2*num, ...double(rest)];
  }
  return []; // <−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− note
}
console.log(double([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: Much better explained than mine

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot in understanding what was wrong. I tried your implementation and it works like a charm. However, I tried your solution without returning [ ] at the end as well, and it seems to work just fine anyway. Is there any case when the lack of return [ ] might break the function down?

Comment: @Nicola when passing an empty array.

Answer (score 23):

Your logical error has been pointed out in comments and answers, but let me point out a cleaner, simpler, less bug-prone way to write this which is more in line with basic principles of recursion.

```
function double([head, ...tail]) {
  if (head === undefined) return [];
  return [2*head, ...double(tail)];
}
```

In other words, there is only one "base case", namely the empty array, which returns an empty array. Everything else is simple recursion.

You could "functionalize" this further with

```
function map(fn) {
  return function iter([head, ...tail]) {
    return head === undefined ? [] : [fn(head), ...iter(tail)];
  };
}

const double = map(x => 2*x);
console.log(double([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: +1 for the points-free style. Good to see more and more people using functional programming correctly in the Javascript world.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I can't say I'm fully grasping these Haskell concepts like point-free, monads and stuff, but reading a bit about it, could you explain why it's point-free if the parameters of the function are present ?

Comment: Very clean and elegant solution, thanks. The only reason I didn't tick your answer is because it wasn't so easy to grasp without the rest of the explanations, but as said thanks! :)

Comment: Using a regular undefined check (`head === undefined`) might make this even neater.

Comment: What I like about this answer is that it only has one base case, not two (`length = 0` and `length = 1`).

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor change:

```js
function double(array) {
  // note the return here is an array, not a number
  if (array.length === 1) return [2 * array[0]];

  var [num, ...rest] = array;
  if (rest.length) return [2 * num, ...double(rest)];
}

console.log(double([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

You were returning a number, and destructuring a number will leave you with an error.

```
...5 // throws SyntaxError
```

Comment: It's intellectually unsatisfying that the `2 *` appears in two places.

Comment: @torazaburo I agree. Your answer is definitely the right one, both in fixing the error and simplifying.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error I get using `node@6.10.3`

```
if (rest.length!=0) return [2*num, ...double(rest)];  
                                        ^

TypeError: double(...)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
    at double (/home/henrique/labs/test.js:4:41)
    at double (/home/henrique/labs/test.js:4:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/henrique/labs/test.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
```

Which probably means that the result of the evaluation of some of your function call is not an iterable.

The error is here:

```
if (array.length===1) return 2*array[0];
```

Change to:

```
if (array.length===1) return [2*array[0]];
```

and it will work.

Comment: Also @TJCrowder correctly identified that you are missing a corner case: the empty array.

Comment: That's not a corner case.

Comment: Well, I guess this is a semantical issue, but why exactly not?

Comment: From Wikipedia: *In engineering, a corner case (or pathological case) involves a problem or situation that occurs only outside of normal operating parameters—specifically one that manifests itself when multiple environmental variables or conditions are simultaneously at extreme levels*.

Comment: Yeah, from that definition, I must agree with you.