# Using {} in React

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between using {} and not when passing in properties?

Ie

```
TodoApp = ({props}) => {
    console.log(props)
}
```

and

```
TodoAp = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the name of the ... operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44786495/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ES6 syntax and not react.

as written in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
> makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
> objects, into distinct variables.

To the specific example,
In the first example you will unpack the object and take the "props" property out of it, where in the second example you will get the whole object and in order to get the property called "props" you will have to write `props.props`