# Spread syntax doesn't work to destructive an array

Tags: javascript, rest, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I am new to Javascript and is confused why the following won't work?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var spread = ...array;
```

I was expecting it would become `1, 2, 3, 4`. Instead, it gave an error message `Unexpected token ...`. Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way, however you're not gaining anything doing that.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var spread = [...array];
console.log(spread);
```

If you really want to destructure that array, you need *destructuring assignment*:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var [one, two, three, four] = array;

console.log(one, two, three, four);
```

Comment: Thanks Ele, so we can't simply use `...` to spread an array literals?

Comment: @geekydude703 no, we can't.  We need to wrap our objects with either `[]` for array or `{}` for key-value pairs objects.  The only place where it's "not necessary" is for example: `[1, ...array, 3, 4]` looks like you don't need the brackets because the spread syntax is not surrounded by them, however, that array along with the others objects are between `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing what you want is:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var spread = [...array];
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I am a little confused when do we need `[]`..in MDN, they have the following examples where there is no brackets when destructing the array: `var parts = ['shoulders', 'knees'];` 
`var lyrics = ['head', ...parts, 'and', 'toes'];` 
// `["head", "shoulders", "knees", "and", "toes"]`

Comment: You need [] because you are destructuring an array into a new array. In that example you are creating a `parts` array and then creating another `lyrics` array, that contains `'head'` and another array inside (the `parts` array), but instead of doing 

`var lyrics = ['head', parts]`, you are using Rest parameters to indicate that you want the parts to be unpacked into distinct variables.

`var lyrics = ['head', ...parts,  'and', 'toes']`

I hope I helped you and not made it even more confusing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: as far as I know, rest parameters (`...`) would only work as parameters in functions. In all other cases, they should be spread syntax. The example I quoted was from MDN spread syntax documentation. I appreciate your help though

Comment: Yeah, in that scenario I believe spread operator is the name I was looking for, thanks for poiting that out. check @Manishz90's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898512/spread-operator-vs-rest-parameter-in-es2015-es6. Helped me understand about different use cases of the three dot syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for using `spread` is:

**For function calls:**

```
myFunction(...iterableObj);
```

**For array literals or strings:**

```
[...iterableObj, '4', 'five', 6];
```

**For object literals (new in ECMAScript 2018):**

```
let objClone = { ...obj };
```

So, based on the syntax, for an array by using `spread` you are missing the square brackets `[]`:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var spread = [...array];
console.log(spread);
```