# What is "..." (3 dots) in javascript?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I learned about this thing from [this post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750).

```
function StoreMixin(...stores) { // what is "..."
  var Mixin = {
    getInitialState() {
      return this.getStateFromStores(this.props);
    },
    componentDidMount() {
      stores.forEach(store =>
        store.addChangeListener(this.handleStoresChanged)
      );
      this.setState(this.getStateFromStores(this.props));
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
      stores.forEach(store =>
        store.removeChangeListener(this.handleStoresChanged)
      );
    },
    handleStoresChanged() {
      if (this.isMounted()) {
        this.setState(this.getStateFromStores(this.props));
      }
    }
  };
  return Mixin;
}
```

Please kindly explain what is "...", with example code. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898512/spread-syntax-vs-rest-parameter-in-es2015-es6)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In that example, the `...` is a [Rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), a syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

It is somewhat similar (or not :), but it's not the same as the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

In your example, the `stores` argument inside is an array. If `function StoreMixin(...stores)` is called like `StoreMixin(1,2,3)` then `stores` will be `[1, 2, 3]` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, this is the part that confuses me. Since the syntax is the same, how does Javascript knows if I want to put all params in an array(Rest parameter), or destruct an object into variables(spread syntax)? If they both are used in function params.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu - Destructuring of function arguments is simply not the same syntax.  Easy for the interpreter to tell the difference.

Comment: Actually, only rest parameters can be used in functions arguments **declarations**. You can't use spread there.  Spread is used everywhere *else*, though.

Comment: @acdcjunior I see. "..." is the same, but it is "rest" operator in function definition, "spread" is used in function invocation. gosh... Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is best not to think of it as an operator. It is part of the function declaration syntax overall, and in that context it can mean only one thing. Spread is part of call and array syntax, and in that context the ellipsis can only be spread.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu: Consider `()`. It's used for three different things: Function definition, function call and as grouping operator. The context makes it clear what the meaning of `()` is.