# I have question about JavaScript Feature ——destructuring_assignment

Tags: javascript

JS Code Example:

```
[1,2,...undefined]
throw error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable.
but, use object destructuring
{a: 1, b: 2, ...undefined} = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

Why?

Comment: The first line isn't destructuring - it's spreading and you cannot spread `undefined`. You can, however, assign to it, which is why the second one works.

Comment: One can only iterate data-types, which implement iterable (similar to Java).

Comment: `...` means different things in different contexts. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line, you are unpacking a variable with the `...` syntax, called [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and are expecting a value in that position of the array.

In your second line, you are not spreading, you're using ["rest properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898512/spread-syntax-vs-rest-parameter-in-es2015-es6) but you're not expecting a value back from the spreading of `undefined`, so that's why it's simply ignored and treated as empty.

Comment: The second case is not using "spread". They are using something that I would call "rest properties". All the renaming properties (of which there are none), are collected in a new object and assigned to `undefined` (which is readonly).