# Getting Function Arguments Using (...args)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can somebody explain to me, in detail, how the spread operator works when used to get the parameters of an input function (function passed in as a parameter to another function)?

For example, consider a simple `throttle` function:

```js
const throttle = (func, wait) => {
  let halt = false
  return function(...args) {
    if (!halt) {
        func.call(this, ...args)
        halt= true
        setTimeout(()=>halt=false, wait)
    }
  }
}
```

In the above sample, `...args` is used twice, once as the parameter of the inner arrow function, and the other time is passed as parameters to the `func` call.

I am having a hard time understanding what `...args` is exactly. I know that if you use `...` on an array of items, it will simply deconstruct the array and spread them out to individual items. But what exactly is being spread here when the expected parameters are a function(probably with its own parameters) and a number? Also, when using the `apply` on `func`, why are we spreading again?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898512/spread-syntax-vs-rest-parameter-in-es2015-es6)

Comment: Btw, the `this` keyword doesn't work as one would expect to when you use an arrow function here. Use a normal `function` instead for the returned closure.

Comment: @Bergi Oh yes you are correct since the arrow function has a lexical ```this```. And I guess I am still a little confused, so maybe clarify this for me: the first ```...args``` is the spread operator, and the second ```...args``` is the rest operator correct? How is this getting me the parameters passed into the ```func`` function?

Comment: @Isaac The other way round. And [neither is an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934828/1048572). In a parameter list, it's the rest parameter syntax, in a function call, it's spread syntax.

Comment: "*when using the apply on func, why are we spreading again?*" - you're not using `apply`, your using `call`. But you're right, if the code was using `apply`, it would be just `func.apply(this, args)`, no spread syntax.

Comment: @Bergi Ah thank you! That makes a lot more sense now :)