# Zustand store slices

Tags: zustand

I have started learning Zustand and I'm going through the documentation. I'm reading about splitting the store into multiple slices, like in Redux, but don't exactly understand the code shared on the website. The code is from [this site](https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/guides/slices-pattern).

On this page is the following code block:

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { createBearSlice } from './bearSlice'
import { createFishSlice } from './fishSlice'

export const useBoundStore = create((...a) => ({
  ...createBearSlice(...a),
  ...createFishSlice(...a),
}))
```

I don't understand what the "a" argument is in the create function. I know when creating a new store we can pass "set" and "get" arguments to create(). But, can't figure out what this "a" argument is and why it's being spread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spread Syntax vs Rest Parameter in ES2015 / ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898512/spread-syntax-vs-rest-parameter-in-es2015-es6)

Comment: Same as `create((set, get) => ({ ...createBearSlice(set, get), ...createFishSlice(set, get) }))`

Comment: @Bergi Just to be absolutely clear, the "a" argument is the "set" and "get" arguments??

Comment: `a` is an array `[set, get]` (and any further arguments, if they are passed)

Answer (score 0):

...a in the parameter list of the arrow function inside create() means that the function can accept any number of arguments, and those arguments will be collected into an array called a.

In the context of the create() function from the Zustand library (a state management library for React), which is being used to define a store, ...a means that the createBearSlice and createFishSlice functions can be called with any number of arguments, and they will both receive the same arguments.

In this case it will be [set, get].