# Use all function arguments without having to enumerate them

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I have functionWithManyArguments(arg1,...,arg15).

Can I  log all arguments without having to enumerate them all?

Comment: Either use rest (preferred) or `arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You could do something like:-

```js
function foo(...args) {
  console.log(...args);
}
foo(1, 2, "a")
```

`...args` are rest parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to name all the arguments because every one of them are used in some logic. The reason why I need to use all of them at once is because I want to test if all args are defined else it returns an error.