# Is there any downside to using the spread operator in a react component instantiation?

Tags: reactjs

Instead of writing this:

```js
<FilterBar filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters} />
```

I like to write this when the props and the variables are the same name as a shorthand.

```js
<FilterBar {...{ filters, setFilters }} />
```

Is there any downside to doing this performance-wise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does spread operator affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55843097/does-spread-operator-affect-performance)

Comment: *"But, on modern computers, and on modern JS engines, the processing power required is next to nothing; what does it matter, when millions of instructions can be processed each second? A handful of key-value pairs is nothing to worry about."*